# Label com valor do input range

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

Boa tarde.
Estou utilizando o `BOOTSTRAP 4` especificamente um input range assim:

```
<div class='col slider'>
    <label for="customRange3"><strong>BRIGHTNESS</strong><span class='float-right badge badge-primary lbval' id='brightnesslabel'>0</span></label>
    <input type="range" class="custom-range" min="-64" max="64" step="1" id="brightness">                       
</div>
```

e tenho um java script que atualiza o `Badge` que esta assim :

```
<script>

        var slider = document.getElementById("brightness");
        var output = document.getElementById("brightnesslabel");
        output.innerHTML = slider.value;

        slider.oninput = function() {
          output.innerHTML = this.value;
        }    

</script>
```

Estou apanhando em tornar esta função `javascript` em uma função `jquery` usando `.each()` pois quero copiar esses blocos para ter vários ranges e realizar um `.each(".slider")`

Alguém pode me auxiliar ?

estou tentando fazer desta forma:

```
$( ".slider" ).each(function() {
   $( this + ' > .lbval').html($( this + ' .custom-range').val());
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

eu utilizei desta forma mas vou alterar pela forma que você propôs:

```
$( ".slider" ).mousemove(function() {
    $(this).find('.lbval').html($(this).find('.custom-range').val());
});
```

postei a caráter de consulta e estudos.

Answer (score 1):

Função jQuery:

```
<script>
    $('input[type=range]').on('input', function () {
        $(this).trigger('change');
        $("#brightnesslabel").html($(this).val());
    });
</script>
```

Caso queira pegar um range especifico ou uma classe deles, basta substituir:

```
$('input[type=range]')
```

pelo **#id** ou **.classe** desejada.

Comment: e no caso se eu utilizar a mesma função mas no lugar do input eu colocar um change eu posso utilizar ela para salvar o dado logo depois de alterado ne?